# How do we get IE to refresh a flash.swf file every time the page is loaded?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, flash, internet-explorer

When a user visits our site they see a coverflow. They are not logged in so they cant see any images. Once they log in they should be able to see images in the coverflow but they cant because the flash object is being cached.

A user can get around this problem by setting the IE settings to (check for newer versions of stored pages every time they visit a site) however we need a way to force the browser to refresh the flash object once they are logged in, without telling all of our users to change the settings in their browser.

Is this possible?

I have tried adding the following:

```
<div class="flash">
        <script type=text/javascript>
        AC_FL_RunContent(
           'codebase', 'http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0',
           'width', '600',
           'height', '225',
           'src', 'streaming_flow2_v8?math=<%= random %>',
           'quality', 'high',
           'pluginspage', 'http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer',
           'align', 'middle',
           'play', 'true',
           'loop', 'true',
           'scale', 'showall',
           'wmode', 'transparent',
           'devicefont', 'false',
           'id', 'streaming_flow2_v8?math=<%= random %>',
           'bgcolor', '#ffffff',
           'name', 'streaming_flow2_v8?math=<%= random %>',
           'menu', 'true',
           'allowScriptAccess','sameDomain',
           'allowFullScreen','true',
           'movie', 'streaming_flow2_v8?math=<%= random %>',
           'salign', ''
           );
        </script> 
        <noscript>
        <embed 
        src="streaming_flow2_v8.swf?math=<%= random %>" 
        width="600" 
        id="<%= random %>"
        height="225" 
        allowscriptaccess="always" 
        allowfullscreen="true" 
        flashvars="address=/playlist.aspx?math=<%= random %>"
        />
        </noscript>
    </div>
```

You can see my inline c# script to generate random numbers but that doesnt seem to refresh the object.

Comment: Once the user has logged in does the page refresh? If so, instead of setting a random number to the end of the swf you could pass a parameter as a FlashVar like loggedIn=true

Comment: Not sure I follow you however I have tried setting random variables in the flash vars and the attributes of the embed object and it just isnt refreshing the object, its so annoying...

Comment: I've always had to close the browser and re-open.  it sucks but it works every time.

Comment: Not really a suitale solution to give to our 50 or so corporate client :-( much as I would like to :-)

Comment: I don't know the asp solution so I'm posting as a comment. I assume the php solution is practically identical. I would write a small php script that has a header that looks like this: header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); a date that expires in the past header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); - the correct header for swf files "application/x-shockwave-flash" and then I would read in the swf with readfile(). I would then link to the php file instead of the swf file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the querystring is not affecting .SWF files, only the file name.

To bust this, try creating .aspx file called `streaming_flow2_v8.aspx` and in that file set all the Cache headers to expire immediately and "no-cache" etc.. then Redirect to the actual flash file.

Also don't forget to call it like this `streaming_flow2_v8.aspx?math=<%= random %>`

Can't guarantee it will work but it's worth trying and have good chance of success. :)